# SQL calendar table to fill missing date values for cumulative sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate cumulative sum of registered users by company name (my raw data is user registration logs - user id, company name, registration date)

screenshot of my current output versus what I need:

[image]

here is my code that is populating current output (I know I need to join to a calendar table, but I need to populate the company name with each quarter value, to join registered users to - not sure how to do that)

````
WITH 
  users AS (
    SELECT
      company_name AS company,
      DATE_TRUNC(registration_date , QUARTER) AS quarter,
      count(distinct(email)) AS registered_users,
      FROM `table` AS registered_users
      GROUP BY quarter, company
      ORDER BY quarter)


SELECT 
  users.company as company,
  users.quarter as quarter,
  users.registered_users as new_registered_users,
  sum(registered_users) OVER (PARTITION BY users.company ORDER BY users.quarter) as total_registered_users
  FROM users
  ORDER BY company, quarter```
````

Comment: have you try to look at the bigquery doc using while loop to iterate over the wanted dates. Check doc here => https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#loops

Comment: Your code looks correct.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of dummy data? So I can reproduce the case ?